# What is CAPT & PURS?

Tags: aircraft-systems, airbus-a320

On the airbus A320 Evacuation Control Panel, what is CAPT & PURS. On some takeoffs it is selected and on other takeoffs it is not selected. What does this stand for and what is it? What does it do?

Here is a graphical representation:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

It is a two position [tumbler switch](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/switches/toggle-switches-accessories/toggle-switches/) on the overhead panel to allow/disable the activation of the Evacuation alert from the cabin (explained [here](http://www.a320homecockpit.de/downloads/a320flightdeckdocumentation26202.pdf) page 13). The view can also be found [here](http://meriweather.com/flightdeck/320/over/evac.html) for A320 and also [here](http://mobile.airlinetechs.com/airbus/panels/21VU.html), with the following comments:

- `CAPT and PURS` - the alert may be activated from either cockpit or cabin.
- `CAPT` - the alert may be activated from cockpit only.

The A320 pictures seem containing the safety wire to keep the switch in the `CAPT and PURS` position, so it most likely another position is only selected for the reason.

The manual says *Allows activation of an Evacuation alert from
the cockpit **or** cabin* but from explanation above and the notation on the panel looks like the alert activation from the cocpit cannot be disabled by this switch.

This electric component is also called "toggle switch" and may be called "flush switch". These components were patented as early as [in 1917](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pages/US1233597-0.png).

Comment: I assume the abbreviations stand for "captain" and "purser?"

Comment: I thought you used "tumbler" by mistake, but I see that it is a valid use of the word. Maybe a Commonwealth English term? Is it a term that Airbus uses? I am used to using "toggle switch" instead.

Comment: The discussion of the history and nomenclature of toggle switches doesn't seem to be germane to the question